# Which SSL certificates can I use on IIS7?

Tags: c#, iis, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I need to upload SSL certificates to server from .NET code.

I want to create validation on server side to check if certificate has valid format.

Does anybody know which formats are supported by IIS (.pfx, .cer, .crt etc)?

Also I found two classes to work with certificates `X509Certificate` and `X509Certificate2`. Which of them should I use?

Comment: Radislav - was the answer helpful for you?

Comment: And you have also 4 question in one - better post the rest as extra questions

Comment: Radislav - why to you post the questions - and after you ingore giving any feeedack?

Comment: Because I asked just two questions - not 4. Because I asked which certificates formats are supported - not how to install them. Do you really think that I posted questions here without any research before?

Comment: I made +1 just because you tried to answer.

Comment: You also asked about difference X509Certificate and X509Certificate2.

Comment: And yes it is 2 questions in one - not 4

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tutorial to your question: [Installing an SSL Certificate in Microsoft IIS 7](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-7)

and also maybe interesting: [Generating a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) - Microsoft IIS7](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4800/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr-microsoft-iis7)

To answer you question about `X509Certificate` and `X509Certificate2` take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1182626/502950)