# Rest API Client configuration in web.config C#

Tags: c#, wcf, restful-url, wcf-rest

I need to use Https mutual authentication in a rest API client  since we only get the URI we can not add client certificate as we do for WCF.
So I have added keys in my web .config as below :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="URI" value="https://localhost:8080/RestfulAPI/RestfulService.svc/restfulData" />
    <add key="CertificateValue" value="certficatename"/>
    <add key="CertificateLocation" value="LocalMachine"/>
    <add key="CertificateStoreName" value="My"/>
    <add key="CertificateFindType" value="FindBySubjectName"/>
</appSettings>
```

and I am using it in my client code as below:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateStoreName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateLocation"]);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509CertificateCollection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateFindType"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateValue"], true);
            X509Certificate certificate = certificates[0];
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse
```

Is this the right way to implement mutual authentication in REST API client ?

Or if not can someone please help me with the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mutual Authentication is a security feature in which a client process
>   must prove its identity to a server, and the server must prove its
>   identity to the client, before any application traffic is sent over
>   the client-to-server connection.

([source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961730.aspx))

This is also called sometimes a 2-way SSL authentication.

What you're doing shows the right intent for achieving this because:

1. You add the client certificate when creating the request
2. You use HTTPS to communicate with the server

My only suggestion is (if this is a strict requirment) to enforce this process by:

1. Make sure the request is not made if a client ceritificate is not found
2. Provide a `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` method where you can add custom validaton (or enforcment policies) when validating the server certificate
3. Use `X509Certificate2` and `X509Certificate2Collection` classes instead ([see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182612/what-is-the-difference-between-x509certificate2-and-x509certificate-in-net))

Comment: Hey thanks @AlinG I also need to make certificate details configurable ,is there any other way of doing it except the one i have mentioned in the above post ?

Comment: app.config and querying cert store is one way, since this is a client application you might also want to add support for loading the certificate from a file; for that you can use [X509Certificate2 Ctor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148420(v=vs.110).aspx) and optionally allow them to provide a password to access the certificate (this way user doesn't need to install the certificate).